# No component found with Camel Bean Validator

Tags: java, validation, apache-camel, bean-validation

I am getting in route: `Route(directRoute)[[From[direct-vm:getAddress]] -> [To[bean-v... because of Failed to resolve endpoint: bean-validator://validator?validationProviderResolver=myValidationProviderResolver due to: No component found with scheme: bean-validator`

I have added the following dependency :

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
</dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-bean-validator</artifactId>
      <version>2.12.0</version> 
    </dependency>
```

Also I am manually initializing the HibernateValidationProviderResolver because I am using Camel version 2.12.0. I am adding the following line in my camel-context.xml

```
<bean id="myValidationProviderResolver" class="com.beanvalidation.example.BeanValidation.HibernateValidationProviderResolver"/>
```

And this is how my validator bean is getting called is getting called :

```
<from uri="direct-vm:getAddress"/>
        <to uri="bean-validator:validator?validationProviderResolver=myValidationProviderResolver"/>
```

Here is my class HibernateValidationProviderResolver which I include separately in my class and call while I call the validator!

```
HibernateValidationProviderResolver implements ValidationProviderResolver {

      @Override
      public List getValidationProviders() {
        return singletonList(new HibernateValidator());
      }

    }
```

Here is the pom file to get the clear idea..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
        <parent>
            <groupId>com.example.parent.pom</groupId>
            <artifactId>build</artifactId>
            <version>0.1.2</version>
        </parent>

        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

        <groupId>com.example.bean-validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>getAddress</artifactId>
        <packaging>bundle</packaging>
        <version>0.0.8-SNAPSHOT</version>

        <name>Integration :: Service :: UK Address</name>

        <properties>
            <jackson.version>1.9.10</jackson.version>
        </properties>

        <dependencies>

            <!-- cxf -->
            <!-- regular http transport -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
                <version>${cxf.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                <artifactId>cxf-rt-core</artifactId>
                <version>${cxf.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                <artifactId>cxf-bundle</artifactId>
                <version>${cxf.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                <artifactId>cxf-api</artifactId>
                <version>${cxf.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.osgi</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-osgi-core</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <scope>compile</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.7.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.7.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- Core -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.example.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>core</artifactId>
                <scope>provided</scope>
                <version>1.0.10</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- cxf web container for unit testing x-->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty</artifactId>
                <version>${cxf.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
                <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
                <version>${camel.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
                <artifactId>camel-cxf</artifactId>
                <version>${camel.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
                <artifactId>camel-test</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
                <version>${camel.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
                <artifactId>camel-test-spring</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
                <version>${camel.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.osgi</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-osgi-mock</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version> 
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.0</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.jettison</groupId>
                <artifactId>jettison</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.5</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
                <artifactId>camel-jackson</artifactId>
                <version>${camel.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs</artifactId>
                <version>1.9.10</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
                <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
                <artifactId>camel-bean-validator</artifactId>
                <version>${camel.version}</version> 
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
                <version>5.0.1.FINAL</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jboss.logging</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>

        </dependencies>

        <build>
            <!-- defaultGoal>install</defaultGoal -->

            <plugins>
                <!-- to generate the MANIFEST-FILE of the bundle -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${cxf.version}</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>generate-sources</id>
                            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                            <configuration>
                                <sourceRoot>${basedir}/target/generated-sources/jaxws</sourceRoot>
                                <wsdlOptions>
                                    <wsdlOption>
                                        <wsdl>${basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/out/neweb.wsdl</wsdl>
                                    </wsdlOption>

                                </wsdlOptions>
                            </configuration>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.3.4</version>
                    <extensions>true</extensions>
                    <configuration>

                        <instructions>  
                            <Bundle-SymbolicName>getAddress</Bundle-SymbolicName>

                            <Import-Package>                    
                                javax.jws,
                                javax.jws.soap,
                                javax.xml.bind,
                                javax.xml.bind.annotation,
                                javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters,
                                javax.xml.datatype,
                                javax.xml.namespace,
                                javax.xml.ws,
                                javax.ws.rs,
                                javax.ws.rs.core,
                                javax.validation,
                                javax.validation.constraints,
                                javax.validation.metadata,
                                org.apache.camel,
                                org.apache.camel.component.http,
                                org.apache.camel.spring.spi,
                                org.apache.commons.httpclient,
                                org.apache.commons.httpclient.params,
                                org.apache.cxf.feature,
                                org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.json,
                                org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils,
                                org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs,
                                org.slf4j,
                                javax.validation.bootstrap,
                                org.hibernate.validator
                            </Import-Package>
                            <Require-Bundle>org.apache.cxf.bundle</Require-Bundle>
                        </instructions>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>

        </build>

    </project>
```

Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `camel-bean-validator` doesn't allow the setting of `validationProviderResolver` until version 2.13 of Camel, as mentioned in the [documentation](http://camel.apache.org/bean-validation.html).

Comment: Yes that is why I included HibernateValidationProviderResolver in a separate package and I am referring it in the camel-context.xml. I have edited the question for the same.

Comment: Version 2.12 of the bean-validator component doesn't know about the option. It is ignored, regardless of whether you created a bean. This doesn't help you with the `No component found` error, which I suspect is because of something wrong with your `pom.xml` configuration.

Comment: So is there any way I can use camel-bean validation with camel 2.12.0 ?

Comment: Yes, you can, but you cannot specify the `validationProviderResolver` as it uses a default in 2.12. Your biggest issue is that you must figure out why the dependency you specified doesn't seem to work. Perhaps add your pom.xml file above so we can see what's going on?

Comment: Ok, I have edited the question to include pom.xml. Have a look!

Comment: Since you're not including the package `org.apache.camel.component.bean.validator` in your list of imported packages, I suspect that your bundle is missing the `bean-validator` component. Try removing the `Import-Package` instruction completely for the maven-bundle-plugin. By default, it will include all packages which your project requires (an implicit `*`). Very rarely does this instruction need to be used. Check out the docs on the plugin for more details.

Comment: Thanks Adam, I tried removing the Import-Package completely and put a * there. But it still shows the No Component Found error. It is still missing the bean-validator component it seems.